# General expression for interpolating polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, interpolation

Given $S = \{ (x_0, a_0), (x_1, a_1), \dots (x_n,a_n) \}$ we know there exist an unique polynomial of degree $\leq n$ such that $p(x_i) = a_i$ for $i = 0, \dots, n$, the Lagrange interpolating polynomial.

I am trying to find a general expression for all the interpolating polynomials (of any degree) of this set. It is clear that if $q$ is a polynomial such that $q(x_i) = 1$ for all $i = 1, \dots, n$ then $pq$ is an interpolating polynomial of those points. Are all interpolating polynomials like this?

Comment: Hint: $\,p(x)+q(x)\,$ is an interpolating polynomial iff $q(x_i)=0$.

Comment: @Zanzag If we take the basis polynomials to be in Newton's form, then a polynomial of degree $n$ interpolates $\{(x_i,y_i):i=0\ldots k\}$ (with distinct $x_i$) iff it is of form $\sum_{j=0}^na_jb_j(x)$, where $b_j(x)=\prod_{i=1}^{j-1}(x-x_i), b_0(x)=1,$ and $a_{j\le k}=[y_0,\ldots,y_k]$ (divided differences). Here $a_{j>k}$ and $x_{j>k}$ are just appropriate constants (still keeping all $x_i$ distinct).  E.g., $p(x)=1\cdot 1+1\cdot(x-1)$ and $h(x)=1\cdot 1+1\cdot(x-1) + 1\cdot(x-1)(x-2)$ both interpolate $\{(1,1), (2,2)\}$.